# Camel route SNMP Trap route - No response for V3 traps

Tags: apache-camel, snmp, net-snmp, spring-camel, snmp4j

I am new in Camel, trying to create a SNMP Camel route

from("snmp:0.0.0.0:162?protocol=udp&type=TRAP&securityName="
+ new OctetString("MD5DES")+"&snmpVersion="+SnmpConstants.version3+"&securityLevel="
+SecurityLevel.AUTH_PRIV+"&authenticationPassphrase="+snmpuser +
"privacyPassphrase=" + snmppass
+ "&authenticationProtocol=MD5&privacyProtocol=DES").log("{body}");

Once the route is started, I can send snmp Trap from snmptrap commnad for Version V1 and V2 and do not get any auth error and traps are received in the code and printed , but when I send V3 trap from snmptrap command, it shows success on sender side , but nothing is received on Camel code.

snmptrap -v 3 -u user -a MD5 -A password -x DES -X password -l 3 127.0.0.1 '' 1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.0.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.2.1 i 12335

Appreciate any help.

Comment: http://snmpsharpnet.com/index.php/sending-snmp-version-3-traps/ The reason behind is that "Since you are both the originator of the notification and authoritative SNMP engine, there is nothing you need to “discover” making SNMP version 3 Trap notifications the only SNMP operation that doesn’t use the discovery procedure."

Comment: @Lex LI - Thanks for the response, so if run the SNMP camel server on another machine and send the trap as below - it should work ?

snmptrap -v 3 -u user -a MD5 -A password -x DES -X password -l 3 "IP Address'' 1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.0.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.2.1 i 12335